# Limit at Infinity of Rational Function

Tags: calculus, limits, algorithms

I'm following the Algorithm Design book by Eva Trados. In the 'Basics of Algorithm Analysis' chapter, I've come across a proof that I'm having difficulty understanding and can't find any proper explanation for it.

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }  \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = c > 0 
$$
Given two functions f and g, the proof uses the fact that if a positive limit exists for the limit above, then there is some value $ n_{0} $ beyond which the ratio is always between $\frac{1}{2}c$ and 2c.

What I don't understand is, how do we know that the ratio is between $\frac{1}{2}c$ and 2c ?

Comment: That is true for any sequence $(a_n)$ with limit $c\gt 0$.

Comment: I am trying to understand the reasoning behind it. Can you direct me to some reading or book that explains this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a_n)$ be *any* sequence with limit $c\gt 0$. Then by the *definition* of limit, for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $|a_n-c|\lt \epsilon$.

Pick $\epsilon=\frac{c}{2}$. Then there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ we have 
$|a_n-c|\lt \frac{c}{2}$, or equivalently
$$c-\frac{c}{2}\lt a_n \lt c+\frac{c}{2}.$$
From this we can conclude that if $n\gt N$ then $\frac{c}{2}\lt a_n\lt 2c$.

Comment: Shouldn't c +  $\frac{c}{2}$  be $ \frac{3}{2}c $?

Comment: @WasifHyder Then you'd get $\frac c 2 <a_n<\frac3 2 c$. But $\frac 3 2 c<2c$, so what you want follows.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks so much! :) Really wish I could upvote this answer.

Comment: Yes, but if $a_n\lt \frac{3}{2}c$ then $a_n\lt 2c$.

Comment: You are welcome. We gave a rather formal answer, but the point is that after a while $a_n$ is very close to $c$. We could have chosen $\epsilon=\frac{c}{10}$, and concluded that there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $9c/10\lt a_n\lt 11c/10$.

Comment: @WasifHyder You can't up vote it, but you can accept it. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).